# gcc7 lambda expression return type without arrow

Tags: c++, gcc

I wrote the following by accident and got no warning with gcc 8:

```
auto f = []() bool {};
```

I've never heard or read anything about the previous syntax. My intent was to write:

```
auto f = []() -> bool {};
```

And in this case gcc issues the very useful warning I expected: `no return statement`.

I did some experiments and GCC accepts the first syntax without warnings or errors since at least GCC 7.1 but not with GCC 6.3. No other compilers seem to accept it. Also, the first syntax is accepted for native types: `bool` `int` `float` and such but not for classes such as`struct A {};`

Is this a bug or Is this a new c++17 or c++20 syntax related to, for instance, attributes?

Comment: What are you passing as `-std=`? Maybe it is a GNU extension?

Comment: I don't pass any option, this happens on the default compiler configuration

Comment: This works only with gcc. Clang, msvc and icc refuse to compile it: https://godbolt.org/g/KdMejp

Comment: C++ is a complex language. Parsing it is therefore also complex, and non-trivial. That means compilers *will* have bugs. In 99.9999 percent of all cases it will *not* be a bug in the compiler, but it seems you found one. :) So I suggest you go and [learn how to submit bugs for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude After some discussion on their IRC, they opened a ticket: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86550

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a fluke.  The code (but not the warnings, as you point out) is the same for both, so long as you have GCC 7 or 8.  But GCC 6 doesn't accept it, nor any other compiler I tried.

It does not appear to be valid C++.  It definitely wasn't added for C++20, because [GCC 7 did not add any C++20 features](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) (though 8 did add some).

Comment: The bug is fixed in GCC9 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86550